# Spring Boot 2 - EmbeddedServletContainerFactory not found

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-web

My Spring Boot 2 web application is working fine but now I want to redirect all http requests to https.

However EmbeddedServletContainerFactory and TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory can not be imported.
It says that **org.springframework.boot.context.embedded** does not exists.

My code is the following:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer(){
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(){
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
    return tomcat;
}
```

I use gradle and the build file is:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M6'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.pilot'
version = '0.0.2'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-release' }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-envers:2.0.2.RELEASE')
    compile('nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect')
    compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4")
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```